# Jquery Ajax call served by Java Socket doesn't get a success response

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, http

```
        //--------- Java Socket Server --------

        package com.company.server;

        import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
        import java.io.StringReader;
        import java.net.Socket;
        import java.util.Properties;

        import org.slf4j.Logger;
        import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

        public class Worker implements Runnable {

            private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Worker.class);

            private Socket socket;

            public Worker(final Socket socketParam) {
                socket = socketParam;
            }

            public void run() {
                logger.trace(String.format("Connection established with %s.", socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()));
                orchestrate();
            }

            public void orchestrate() {
                try {
                    final HttpPacket httpIn = readRequest();
                    respond(httpIn);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public HttpPacket readRequest() throws IOException {
                final HttpPacket httpIn = new HttpPacket();
                    final BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                byte[] streamBuf = new byte[in.available()];
                in.read(streamBuf);

                final String payload = new String(streamBuf, "UTF-8");
                final String[] payloadSplit = payload.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                final StringBuilder headerBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                final StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                boolean bodyField = false;
                for (int i = 0; i< payloadSplit.length; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        String[] firstLine = payloadSplit[0].split("\\s");
                        httpIn.setMethod(firstLine[0]);
                        httpIn.setUrl(firstLine[1]);
                    } else if ("".equals(payloadSplit[i].trim())) {
                        bodyField = true;
                    } else if (bodyField) {
                        bodyBuilder.append(payloadSplit[i]);
                        bodyBuilder.append("\n");
                    } else {
                        headerBuilder.append(payloadSplit[i]);
                        headerBuilder.append("\n");
                    }
                }

                final Properties props = parsePropertiesString(headerBuilder.toString());
                httpIn.setHttpHeaders(props);
                httpIn.setBody(bodyBuilder.toString());
                logger.trace(String.format("Data received from from %s connection:\n%s", 
                        socket.getRemoteSocketAddress(), payload));
                return httpIn;
            }

            public Properties parsePropertiesString(String s) throws IOException {
                final Properties p = new Properties();
                p.load(new StringReader(s));
                return p;
            }

            public void respond(final HttpPacket httpIn) throws IOException {
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                builder.append("Content-Type: text/plain" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                builder.append("Content-Length: " + httpIn.getBody().length() 
                + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                builder.append(httpIn.getBody());
                builder.append(httpIn.getBody());

                out.write(builder.toString());
                out.close();
                socket.close();
            }
        }

    //-------------- JQuery Ajax --------------

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".test").click(function() {
            testMessage();
        });
    });

    function testMessage() {
        var url = "http://localhost/";
            $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : url ,
            contentType: "text/html",
             success : function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(response);
             },
             error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error getting response.");
             }
           });
    };
```

1. Intention - When I click on a button (with class="test" in a html page with this js), it should perform an ajax call and get the response back.
2. Problem - I do not get response body with this ajax call. When I used firebug with mizilla firefox, all I see is "POST http://localhost.uri/ 200 OK -20ms" (forget about the .uri - satisfying this editor) in red with empty body and the error message (ajax error function() is called) in chrome (did not use firebug).
3. HttpPacket is a data structure internal to the app just to store incoming data.

Comment: What error reason is given in your error callback? What errors are appearing in the javascript console? (F12)

Comment: @Avempace - Answered in point 3.

Comment: @KevinB - Error only in chrome. alert("Error: " + jqXHR.responseText); Displays "Error:" [Empty]

Comment: that's not the error reason. `errorThrown` contains the error reason.

Comment: Sorry, did not say that before. Even that is empty.

Comment: 1.) Put some debug output in your server code (e.g.after every builder append) to see what's going on
2.) Why do you use System.getProperty("line.separator") ? You are building the response stream, and that is not server architecture dependent. I hope line.separator is set and you are not running on windows...

Comment: ---> Found the problem. I was running the html file from my local machine by accessing the directory. Looks like the Origin header is null for such requests. All our requests have to be processed from the server. (So the home screen has to be served by the socket server).